# PHP5.3.3の場合、Apache2.4は使用できず、Apache2.2を使用しないといけないのでしょうか。

Tags: php, apache

下記サイト
https://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/archives/
より
「php-5.3.3-Win32-VC9-x86.zip」をダウンロードしてみましたが
解凍後、dllファイルが「php5apache2_2.dll」といった2.2関連のものしかなく2.4のものがありません。
PHP5.3.3の場合、Apache2.4は使用できず、Apache2.2を使用しないといけないのでしょうか。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

そもそもPHP5.3.3のリリースやそのWindows版のビルドが[Apache httpd 2.4のリリース](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server)より1年ほど前なので当然ながらその**Windowsの**モジュール版は対応していません。どころか、[Apache 2.4のハンドラSAPIに公式配布のWindows版のPHPが対応したのは PHP5.5](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/migration55.new-features.php#migration55.new-features.windows-apache)です。

1. そもそもなぜそんな古いPHPの環境(2014年にEOLを迎えています)の環境が必要なのかわかりませんが、Apacheモジュール版であればApache2.2が必要です。(もしかすると例外があるかもしれないけど
2. CGI版、fcgiであればWindowsでApache2.4で使うこともできる気がします。
3. 調べてみると、[PHP5.3.14以降に対応したApache2.4用のモジュールを配ってるサイト](https://www.apachelounge.com/download/additional/)とかもあるようです。なんだか懐かしい雰囲気……
   配布元のスレッドをみる感じ、**PHPを自分でビルドすればこれが用意可能**とのこと。
4. 最も、実働環境があってそれにあわせて5.3とかであればその環境にできるだけよせるのがベストではあります。CentOS6/RHEL6のような環境ではPHP5.3系がぎりぎりメンテされています(5.3.3ではないですが)し、その環境や[Debianなんかでそれらを用意したDockerイメージ](https://github.com/cristianorsolin/docker-php-5.3-apache)すらあります。ちなみにこれはApache 2.4+PHP5.3です。3年前なので今でもつかえるかはわかりませんが。