# Apach 2.4.51 とPHP 5.4以下の組合せで動作可能でしょうか？

Tags: php, apache, cakephp

Apache 2.2.17 + PHP 5.2.1 + CakePHP 1.1.14 で大昔にDB関連WEBを作成しました。
Apacheの脆弱性によりApache 2.4.51 にバージョンアップしたいと考えています。
Apache 2.4.51とPHP 5.5.9での動作は自分で確認できています。

ところが、このままですとCakePHPのバージョンがとても古くてPHP 5.5では動作しないようです。CakePHPのバージョンを1.3まであげることでPHP 5.4なら動作するそうです。

本題ですが、Apach 2.4.51 とPHP 5.4以下の組合せでなんとか動作させることは可能でしょうか？
（CakePHPの2系以上のバージョンアップはできれば避けたいと考えています。）

関連質問：
[PHP5.3.3の場合、Apache2.4は使用できず、Apache2.2を使用しないといけないのでしょうか。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/61981/)

参考：
[CakePHPの適合PHPバージョン一覧](https://ao-system.net/note/183)

Answer (score 1):

関連質問と同じような回答になってしまいますが、脆弱性への対応ということであれば、
PHP 5.4, CakePHP 1.x 共にサポートが終了しており数世代前のバージョンです。

**参考:**
[PHPのリリース日とサポート期限](https://qiita.com/bezeklik/items/72d1ff8393f66673e2bc)

> PHP 7.3 以前のバージョンはセキュリティサポートも含め公式のサポート期間は既に終了している。

実行環境の OS が分かりませんが、例えば Linux だとサポートを終えたバージョンのパッケージは入手が難しい場合があるので (大抵サポートしているバージョンは決まっている)、自力でコンパイル等の対応を行う必要が出てくるかもしれません。